# She was not what she was/had been?

Tags: tense

There is a sentence like, *"She has changed a lot, and she is not what she was."*,
and when it comes to make the tense of this sentence one more past, which do you think is better?

- She had changed a lot, and she was not what she **was**.
- She had changed a lot, and she was not what she **had been**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> She had changed a lot, and she was not what she had been.

The second sentence is correct for that meaning. There is a point in the past (when she "was"), and her changing was before that, and what she had been was before that.

In fact the first sentence has a contradiction:

*she was not what she was

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Come to think of it, " she was not what she was." contains a contradiction. I didn't realize that.